# PhpStorm XDebug through ssh tunnel

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, ssh-tunnel

I have a PhpStorm project with a remote deployment (Ubuntu Server 16.04) through ssh

[image: PhpStorm Deployment configuration]

to test my PHP project I connect to the remote server through a ssh tunnel (putty):

[image: Putty configuration]

where the Dynamic Port forwarding D1024 is used for the browser proxy
and the Remote Port forwarding R9000 localhost:9000 should be used for XDebug

I configured PhpStorm to use XDebug:

[image: PhpStorm CLI Interpeters Configuration]

[image: PhpStorm XDebug configuration]

and enabled it to listen PHP Debug Connections:

[image: PhpStorm PHP Debug Enabled]

XDebug on remote server seems enabled:
[image: PHPInfo1]

this is the XDebug section of phpinfo() in my browser

```
xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.6.0
IDE Key XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   PHPSTORM    PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log   /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

and this one is the xdebug grep of php -i from command line:

```
 php -i | grep xdebug
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log => /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

and my browser is sending the correct cookie, as Debug was enabled from Xdebug Helper Firefox extension:
[image: Cookie]

here's my XDebug configuration in  /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

This is the content of xdebug.log

```
Log opened at 2018-03-23 11:39:26
I: Connecting to configured address/port: locahost:9000.
W: Creating socket for 'locahost:9000', getaddrinfo: No such file or directory.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-03-23 11:39:26
```

When I execute my project, navigating it through my browser (ssh tunnel) nothing happens in PhpStorm (even if I set up a breakpoint at the very start of the script)

Where am I wrong?

Maybe the two port forwarding I set in Putty interfere each other? how can I solve this?

Comment: 1) Collect xdebug log -- it will tell what is happening from xdebug side 2) RTFM -- with `xdebug.remote_connect_back=On` value of `xdebug.remote_host` is IGNORED and autodetected IP is used (`REMOTE_ADDR` most likely) .. which not useful in your setup at all.

Comment: you're right, connect_back derived from a previous try I made, thanks for pointing it out.

It seems no xdebug.log it is written, where I can set it on?

Comment: Docs? `xdebug.remote_log`

Comment: I've activated it and showed this:
Log opened at 2018-03-23 11:39:26
I: Connecting to configured address/port: locahost:9000.
W: Creating socket for 'locahost:9000', getaddrinfo: No such file or directory.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-03-23 11:39:26

Comment: Why it says `locahost`? 1) You have got a typo there -- it should be `localhost` (and that's what error says -- it cannot resolve `locahost` domain) 2) The xdebug settings you have posted clearly use `127.0.0.1` address ... Have you edit it after? 3) Better verify what you have got there from `phpinfo()` output -- xdebug section -- that one that you have originally posted is pretty useless as it shows only top of the table with least useful settings.

Comment: I've edited the question with the complete XDebug section of phpinfo().. It shows "xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1"

Comment: 1) So what new xdebug log has to say? 2) Those settings -- are they taken from `phpinfo()` output captured via browser or console? It has to be the same way as you trying to debug.

Comment: Hi, don't know if useful, but when I did this I had to set up a cookie. There were extensions for Firefox, I think it was called Easy Xdebug

Comment: the settings are taken from phpinfo() output in my browser. I'm debugging using the browser

xdebug.log has nothig new to show

Comment: @JorgeeFG I've set up the cookie using FFox extension

Comment: What do you mean "nothing new"? is it showing *exactly the same* log? if so -- something is very wrong in your setup ... Your xdebug settings now show 9001 port. What port is shows in log? Did you setup SSH tunnel to use that 9001 port? I'm sorry .. but mixing old and new info does not help here (as they show different settings).

Comment: yes, exactly the same log.. something seems really wrong in my setup... I'm here because I'm trying to solve it.

I was thinking that maybe php was using another configuration and made a search  grep -r "locahost" /etc/ in order to find wich configuration file has the typo "locahost" in it, but nothing was found :(

Comment: In the question I've added the result of php -i from my command line, it shows 127.0.0.1 as well

Comment: "locahost" is on your putty config. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks @JorgeeFG

I feel so stupid now, I was struggling in my server configuration and did not paid attention to putty :(

Thanks LazyOne as well, you helped me to understand a lot of how xdebug works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there was a typo in putty tunnel configuration, wrote locahost instead of localhost